# is Debian packaging install file question

Tags: debian, rpm-spec, debian-packaging

I'm trying to convert systemimager.spec %file section (multiple packages) to a Debian/systemimager-subpackage.{install, doc,man} files.

The question is: are dh_* tools smart enough so I can have variables in those install files (example: %perl_vendorlib in spec file)?
Are wildcards allowed (e.g. bin/*).
Can I have optional files (depends on optional features or depends on OS release)

Example: how do I convert this to a Debian install file? (systemimager-common.{install, docs,man})

```
%files common
%defattr(-, root, root)
%{_bindir}/si_lsimage
%{_mandir}/man8/si_lsimage*
%{_mandir}/man7/autoinstall*
%dir %{perl_vendorlib}/SystemImager
%{perl_vendorlib}/SystemImager/Common.pm
%{perl_vendorlib}/SystemImager/Options.pm
%{perl_vendorlib}/SystemImager/UseYourOwnKernel.pm
%{perl_vendorlib}/SystemImager/JConfig.pm
%dir %{_datarootdir}/systemimager
%dir %{_datarootdir}/systemimager/conf
%{_datarootdir}/systemimager/conf/config_scheme.json
%dir %{_sysconfdir}/systemimager
%config %{_sysconfdir}/systemimager/UYOK.modules_to_exclude
%config %{_sysconfdir}/systemimager/UYOK.modules_to_include
```

Many thanks for help as my googling failed to get valuable infos about content of those files.

Comment: After testing, it seems that wildcard "*" is working. What about variables?